# How to trim white space in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an input that accepts user input and returns an array of strings. Now the user can input one string  or multiple strings separated by a comma. Now i am pushing the inputs into an array of strings and then sending to an API to get a request. But if there is a space after the comma, then the API does not accept String2. 
So `[String1, String2]` returns only value for String1. How can i remove the white space after the comma if there is one so the result can be `[String1,String2,String3....]`?

Here is a sample [pen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/WNQwXXo)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      inputValue: "",
      myArray: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    createArray() {
      if (this.inputValue !== "") {
        this.myArray.push(this.inputValue.trim());
        console.log(this.myArray);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-layout justify-center>
      <v-flex xs6>
        <v-text-field v-model="inputValue" hint="Comma Separated Entries"></v-text-field>
        <v-btn :disabled="inputValue === ''" @click="createArray">Click Me</v-btn>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused. If your data is an array, then your API should just iterate your array to handle each string in your array, instead of  handle your array as a whole string

Comment: @lhoro I am guessing the API considers the white space before the string and after the comma as a character and messes up the request.

Comment: Do you already have an array?
Or do are you making the array before initiating the second api call?

Comment: @lhoro You are right btw. It does not actually considers array as a whole strings rather includes over each string but if there is a space that is also included as well.

Comment: @UtsavPatel Array is generated by the method call i.e. `createArray` which pushes the input value into the empty array. That is how the array is being generated.

Comment: If it is iterating over strings, it would not take space after the comma. I mean the api.

Comment: hmmm yeah i was under the same assumpton but apparaently it does include the space for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace ', ' with ','

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      inputValue: "",
      myArray: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    createArray() {
      if (this.inputValue !== "") {
        this.myArray.push(this.inputValue.trim().replace(/, +/g, ','));
        console.log(this.myArray);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You sir are a straight up rockstar!!! Thank you. Could you please explain how this logic worked?

Comment: replace function uses regex to replace ', ' or ',' and multiple spaces with just a comma

Comment: Are you sure that is your intention?  You realize that you are inputting multiple values as a single string right?  So you get : myArray=["value1,value2,value3","value4,value5,value6","value7"]